# Changing the size of a string in a vector<string>

Tags: c++, stl

What happens to a vector when one or more of its elements change size?

To elaborate,

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("first string");
    v.push_back("2nd string");
    v[0] += " has increased in size";
}
```

what could/would happen at "v[0] += ..."? Would there be a mass reallocation, to keep the memory contiguous in both string and vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There would be no memory re-allocation in the `vector`, and there almost certainly will be a reallocation for the `string`, although the standard does not say anything about that. The string is like a vector in that it keeps the content separately from the string object itself.

Comment: "there almost certainly will be a reallocation for the string, although the standard does not say anything about that"... there won't be a reallocation if the existing capacity is sufficient to house the resultant string content.

Comment: @TonyDelroy You are right, it depends on the allocated capacity. In the OP's code the length of the string more than doubles after being created from scratch, that's why I think there would be a reallocation.

Answer (score 5):

No. `string` stores its actual string data in separately-allocated memory (modulo short string optimization). The actual size of an object can never change, and is fixed at compile-time. Any such dynamic sizing is accomplished using separately-allocated memory, or hierarchies of objects (e.g. set/map uses a tree of nodes, list uses a double-linked list of nodes, etc).

Answer (score 1):

> Would there be a mass reallocation, to keep the memory contiguous in both string and vector?

The vector's elements are contiguous, but within each contained string there's a pointer off to the dynamically-allocated storage where the textual content is stored (assuming the string is not empty nor short enough to fit in a fixed-sized internal buffer - a technique known as "short string optimisation" which implementations may but aren't required to use).

Now, for both the vector and the strings, it's important to understand the difference between the current size (number of elements/`char` for data) and the capacity (the amount of heap that's already reserved and into which the container can grow without needing to allocate a new area of heap and move elements across.

So, if the existing capacity is sufficient, then the string concatenation happens in place.  If the capacity must be grown, then that one string's pointer to dynamic memory is updated to address a newly allocated and larger heap area, into which the textual content is copied, with the original heap area then released.

The `push_back()` operations can cause the vector to reallocate, but the string objects "own" separate blocks of heap memory.

If you're curious to see what your specific implementation is doing, you can print out your container's `size()` and `capacity()` before and after an operation, as well as the address of the first element....  Still, the amount by which capacity exceeds size after a reallocation is not specified by the Standard, so could even change with compiler flags/version, OS etc..

Diagramatically, something like this:

```
VECTOR:                /-------->[first string's text]...extra capacity...
[ first string object /]
[    second string object   \]
...extra vector capacity...  \-->[second string's text]...extra capacity...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `string` object is a fixed size. If the contained string doesn't fit within the internal storage (if any) provided by the string implementation, it is allocated separately. It is not contiguous with any other string storage, at least not intentionally.